# Ruby: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby

Why do i get this error 'ruby: No such file or directory -- Readingfile.rb (LoadError)' when i run my ruby program to read files?

My code:

```
filename = ARGV.first

txt = open(filename)

puts "Heres your file#{filename}:"
print txt.read

print "TYpe the filename again"
file_again = $stdin.gets.chomp

txt_again = open(file_again)

print txt_again.read
```

Comment: Is that the entire file? Can you post your backtrace? How are you running your program?

Comment: Welcome to SO, and to Ruby!  Leo is right, the backtrace would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

'ruby: No such file or directory -- Readingfile.rb (LoadError)'

Without a stack trace, I can only infer that this error originates from the line `txt = open(filename)`. What's most likely is that the filename (first arg passed into `$ ruby file.rb`) either does not exist or was unspecified (and therefore `nil`).

In order to ensure that your program is resilient to different kinds of input, you should check and handle cases where no valid filename is passed. This can be done with `File#exist?`:

```
puts "Missing filename" and exit! unless filename = ARGV.first
```